# Keyboard Blocking Flatlist React Native

Tags: keyboard, scrollview, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have problem with Keyboard blocking Flatlist.
The UI looks like this

```
<View>
   <View>
      Buttons...
   </View>
   <View>
      Input Field...
   </View>
   <View>
      Input Field...
   </View>
   <View>
      Buttons...
   </View>
   <Flatlist>
</View>
```

When I type on one of the input field, it will display the autocomplete results on Flatlist. The problem is some of the results are blocked by the keyboard.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you make a snack or gif ?

Answer (score 1):

wrap your ui in [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/keyboardavoidingview)